# How to evaluate whether a database package is safe to use or not

Tags: python, database, security

I'm working in Python, but the core question is larger than simply the programming language. I would like to write some data to an azure sql database using a python script I've written. This requires setting up a connection with the database, and google leads me to:

https://docs.devart.com/odbc/sqlazure/python.htm

Looks legit, but (obviously) setting up a connection using this odbc will require inputting my login details. I have no idea if I can trust this package with this data.

My question is therefore how a developer-in-the-know would go about evaluating such a package for security concerns? Is it guesswork, or reading through the entire package?

Advice would be much appreciated!

Comment: You can check [blackduck](https://github.com/blackducksoftware) for any package related security issues.

Comment: No disrespect intended to this devart package (I don't know anything about it) but pyodbc and sqlalchemy are well-established open source options. Indeed, MS has documentation specifically for setting up pyodbc with Azure SQL: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/azure-sql-python-quickstart?view=azuresql&tabs=windows%2Csql-inter

Comment: and @slothrop. Appreciate it.